# Editable and non-editable some ag-grid cells dynamically

Tags: ag-grid

I have to implement editable/non-editable of the corresponding cells in a  particular row depending on datatype selection. When we select datatype="NUMERIC" then it should be editable particular that cell in a row only under Min and Max column instead of full column.

````
Example
```
    $scope.gridOptions.onCellValueChanged = function(event) {
        if (event.colDef.field === 'validation_type') {
            if (event.newValue.name === 'NUMERIC') {
                event.columnApi.getColumn('min_value').editable = true;
            }
        }
    }
```
````

Then it allow all cells of that column editable. But as per my requirement it should be editable only one particular cell. Please suggest.
Screenshots:
[image]

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The easiest place to do this is in your column definitions:

```js
const columnDefs = [
    // ...
    {
        headerName: 'Data Type',
        field: 'validation_type',
    },
    {
        headerName: 'min',
        field: 'min_value',
        editable: function(params) {
            // allow `min_value` cell to be edited for rows with correct `validation_type`
            return params.node.data.validation_type === 'NUMERIC';
        },
    },
    {
        headerName: 'max',
        field: 'max_value',
        editable: function(params) {
            return params.node.data.validation_type === 'NUMERIC';
        },
    },
    // ...
];
```

Comment: Thank you so much, thirtydot. its working perfectly.

Comment: @bilen: I'm not sure that it makes sense to edit pivoted data, since it tends to be summed up values from your base data. Wouldn't you want to edit the base data? Maybe I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: @thirtydot yes you are right i am going to edit only base member. Similar one i am using on my existing control. I have some lines tagged as IS_BASE = X on the backend. So i am making that rows editable only and aggregating their parents once any value changed. If i can do similar approach in this grid, would be great. Users want to enter data in treeview style but with copy paste and auto-aggregate option.

Comment: In this case, if you'd change the validation_type, would the grid be updated automatically to reflect that? For example if you'd like to change the cell content based on editability.

Comment: @Arttu: I would expect so, provided that you're changing `validation_type` in a way that the grid knows about. I don't know for sure though.

Comment: what will be the data-type for `param`